# What are the exact name lookup rules for x op y?

Tags: c++, c++11

When encountering

```
x op y
```

Does ADL find member x.op(y)? Or is the lookup specified as if not x.op(y), then ADL(op, x, y)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Member candidates, non-member candidates (with ADL) and built-in candidates are considered. The best candidate is picked.

*[over.match.oper]/3*

> For a unary `operator @` with an operand of a type whose cv-unqualified version is `T1`, and for a binary `operator @` with a left operand of a type whose cv-unqualified version is `T1` and a right operand of a type whose cv-unqualified version is `T2`, three sets of candidate functions, designated member candidates, non-member candidates and built-in candidates, are constructed as follows:
>
> - If `T1` is a complete class type, the set of member candidates is the result of the qualified lookup of `T1::operator@` (13.3.1.1.1); otherwise, the set of member candidates is empty.
> - The set of non-member candidates is the result of the unqualified lookup of `operator@` in the context of the expression according to the usual rules for name lookup in unqualified function calls (3.4.2) except that all member functions are ignored. However, if no operand has a class type, only those non-member functions in the lookup set that have a first parameter of type `T1` or “reference to (possibly cv-qualified) `T1`”, when `T1` is an enumeration type, or (if there is a right operand) a second parameter of type `T2` or “reference to (possibly cv-qualified) `T2`”, when `T2` is an enumeration type, are candidate functions.
> - For the `operator ,`, the unary `operator &`, or the `operator ->`, the built-in candidates set is empty. For all other operators, the built-in candidates include all of the candidate operator functions defined in 13.6 that, compared to the given operator,
>
>   - have the same operator name, and
>   - accept the same number of operands, and
>   - accept operand types to which the given operand or operands can be converted according to 13.3.3.1, and
>   - do not have the same parameter-type-list as any non-template non-member candidate.

*[over.match.oper]/6*

> The set of candidate functions for overload resolution is the union of the member candidates, the non-member candidates, and the built-in candidates. The argument list contains all of the operands of the operator. The best function from the set of candidate functions is selected according to 13.3.2 and 13.3.3.

Comment: So the Standard does not give priority to any particular set of candidates? That is, if there were x.op(y) and op(x, y) that were equally good, then that would be ambiguous?

Comment: @DeadMG: Yes, is ambiguous. I figured a bit too late where you were actually going with your question...